# Running an infinite loop in a struts action : Error

Tags: java, struts

I am running an infinite loop in a struts action. When the java server (hosted on tomcat) is started it calls the following file which has infinite loop inside it.

```
package Android;

import dao.DBService;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainThread extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";


    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.print("hii<br/>");
        //String flag = "1";
            //String q = "select count(*) from info;";
        int t = -1;
        while(t<0){
        String q = "select * from info;";
        ResultSet rs = DBService.selectData(q);

            while(rs.next())
            {
                int change = uidChange(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(4),out);  //Function that checks for a new mail

                if(change==1 && rs.getString(5).equals("1"))// && rs.getString(5) == 1)
                {
                    int res = sendNotification(rs.getString(3)); //sending notification to GCM Server
                    if(res == 200)
                    {
                        q = "update info set flag = '0' where username = '"+rs.getString(1)+"';";                    
                        DBService.updateData(q);
                    }                    
                }
            }   

       }
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }

    public int uidChange(String usn, String pwd, String lastuid, PrintWriter out)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect("****", usn, pwd);  //Real store location in original code

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);


            UIDFolder in = (UIDFolder) inbox;
            Message[] msg1 = inbox.getMessages();
            long highuid = in.getUID(msg1[msg1.length-1]);

                        inbox.close(true);
                        store.close();

                        if(highuid>Long.parseLong(lastuid))
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return 0;   
        } catch (Exception mex) {

                        return 2;
        }
    }



   public int sendNotification(String regid) throws Exception
   {

        String url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add request header
                String s="New Mail";
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                String KEY = "application/json";
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=***"); //Real key in the original code

        String urlParameters = "{ \"data\": {\n"
                        + "\"msg\": \"" + s + "\"\n"
                        + "},\n"
                        + "\"registration_ids\": [ \""+regid+"\" ] \n"
                        + "}"; 

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(urlParameters);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();               
        return con.getResponseCode();
    }
}
```

This is DBService.java file

```
package dao;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBService
{
  private static Connection con;

  static
  {
   try
  {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maildb";
   String user="root";
   String password="";
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
  }
   catch(Exception ee)
   {
      System.err.println("Error : "+ee.getMessage());
   }
  }
  //method to get Connection Object
  public static Connection getConnection()
  {
    return con;
  }

  //method to perform CUID Operations
  public static int updateData(String sql)
  {
    try{
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    int ur = st.executeUpdate(sql);
    return ur;
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
     System.err.println("UPDATE ERROR : "+ee.getMessage());

     return 0;
    }
  }

  //method to perform SQL Projection Operations
  public static ResultSet selectData(String sql)
  {
    try{
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    return rs;
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
     System.err.println("SELECT ERROR : "+ee.getMessage());

     return null;
    }
  }
}
```

> > > It runs fine for sometime(30 minutes or so), but after sometime I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception. The full trace is below:

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: The HTTP Monitor server side component intercepted and rethrew an error while processing a JSP or servlet. Please see the stack trace under the root cause message below to identify the problem.
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.rethrow(MonitorFilter.java:1656)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:473)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    sun.security.provider.DigestBase.engineDigest(DigestBase.java:163)
    java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate.engineDigest(MessageDigest.java:576)
    java.security.MessageDigest.digest(MessageDigest.java:353)
    com.sun.crypto.provider.HmacCore.doFinal(HmacCore.java:207)
    com.sun.crypto.provider.HmacSHA1.engineDoFinal(HmacSHA1.java:110)
    javax.crypto.Mac.doFinal(Mac.java:546)
    sun.security.ssl.MAC.compute(MAC.java:252)
    sun.security.ssl.MAC.compute(MAC.java:160)
    sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.checkMacTags(InputRecord.java:243)
    sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.decrypt(InputRecord.java:194)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:969)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:124)
    java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:95)
    com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:95)
    com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:60)
    com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:293)
    com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.command(Protocol.java:313)
    com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.examine(IMAPProtocol.java:952)
    com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:974)
    com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:919)
    Android.MainThread.uidChange(MainThread.java:100)
    Android.MainThread.execute(MainThread.java:59)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.
```

Comment: Can you paste code for uidChange() ?

Comment: One of the methods you are calling from within that loop (you are not showing us the code for them) is causing new objects to be created and holding onto their references somewhere (preventing them from being garbage collected). Eventually you are running out of memory. You will have to dig a little deeper. You may want to make use of a good heap analyzer tool. If you are using Eclipse, there is https://www.eclipse.org/mat/. There is also the classic [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html).

Comment: The root cause appears to be in `uidChange()`, but be sure to close the `ResultSet` by calling `rs.close()` at the end of `execute()`.

Comment: @musical_coder The symptom shows itself in `uidChange()` but the leak could be anywhere.

Comment: @Wamiq It's just too hard to tell by simply looking at the code you've posted. This is a non-trivial issue to debug. You're going to have to take the effort to debug the issue a little more on your own, unfortunately. Did you look at any of the heap analysis tools I recommended? They're specifically designed to help you track down leaks like this.

Comment: Yes I got it I suppose.... I tried few things and till now(from 4 hrs), it is now showing any error. What I did was:
1- Use System.gc(); in the while loop of main file..
2- Closing HTTP connection to mail server(using con.disconnect() in function sendNotification() of the main file)...
I dont exactly know wat the problem was, but it now seems to be fixed.. :)

Comment: ... What's the point of an action that never returns? This code makes no sense on multiple levels. The canonical way to represent an infinite loop, btw, is simply `while (true)`. Not only is this an infinite loop where one doesn't make sense, it's a *tight* loop, and will burn your CPU cycles.

Comment: Is there any other way out....I want this code to run infinitely on the server.. ??

Answer (score -1):

while (t < 0) is the culprit. You are not incrementing the value of variable t anywhere so it is always -1  (which is less than 0)

Comment: this is what i did to run the code inside the loop infinitely. Is there any other way around to run a piece of code infinitely...

Comment: sorry, I didn't read the question properly and though infinite loop is the problem. Can you please take a heap dump when out of memory occurs and analyze that to see what is taking memory. If your own application objects are taking space, you will know where the problem is.